# Tweet in-memory PNG plot with Tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, buffer, tweepy

I am trying to tweet an in-memory PNG image of a dataframe plot with Tweepy, but I get the following error: `[Errno 63] File name too long`.

Where am I going wrong?

```
import io
import base64
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import tweepy
...
api = tweepy.API(auth)

over1000Bounds  = df.plot()
fig = over1000Bounds.get_figure()


buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf)
buf.seek(0)
image_png= buf.getvalue()

graphic = base64.b64encode(image_png).decode('utf-8')


api.media_upload(graphic)
```

Comment: Why is this marked pandas?

Comment: I generate the png via the pandas library. But I suppose it's actually with matplotlib / pylab EDIT: I changed the tags to reflect matplotlib

Comment: save the file and upload it's filename.

Comment: @SouyamaDebnath the script will run in a Google Cloud Function. So I didn't want to save to file. Is this misguided?

Comment: Put it in tempfile. That's the only writeable part of cloud functions I think.